# zxing flashlight not displaying on UI

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, zxing

I am using Zxing barcode scanner in my PCL in Xamarin Form. The Issue is flashlight ON/Off option is not displaying on UI. This is very important for me to provide this option to the user.

```
           zxing = new ZXingScannerView
                {
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                    HeightRequest = 400,
                    AutomationId = "zxingScannerView",
                    IsTorchOn = true,


                };

                string _BarCode = "";
                int _CountItems = 0;
                int _scannedItem = 0;
                zxing.OnScanResult += (result) =>
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                    {
                 // doing something that i want with scan result

                });
                overlay = new ZXingDefaultOverlay
                  {

                   ShowFlashButton = true,
                    AutomationId = "zxingDefaultOverlay",

                };
                overlay.HeightRequest = 2;
                overlay.BindingContext = this;
                overlay.FlashButtonClicked += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    zxing.IsTorchOn = !zxing.IsTorchOn;
                };
```

In Assambly info i have already added this line of code

```
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Flashlight)]
```

Can you please tell me what mistake i did in my code. Thanks for comments and suggestions

Comment: Have you tried to use the `ToggleTorch()` method (`overlay.FlashButtonClicked += (sender, e) => zxing.ToggleTorch();`)?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza no can you provide me the reference i will try and let you know

Comment: I wrote it inside the parentheses. Replace your button clicked event handler by this code. It usually works

Answer (score 3):

In a scan button ...

```
       var overlay = new ZXingDefaultOverlay
        {
            ShowFlashButton = true,
            TopText = "Please scan the barcode...",
            BottomText = string.Empty
        };

        overlay.BindingContext = overlay;  

        var scan = new ZXingScannerPage(null, overlay);
        await Navigation.PushAsync(scan);            

        overlay.FlashButtonClicked += (s, ed) => 
        {
            scan.ToggleTorch();
        };

        scan.OnScanResult += (result) =>
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                await Navigation.PopAsync();
                var _scanResult = result.Text;
            });
        };
```